# Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it error oracle db

Tags: oracle, triggers

I got a problem when updating a column. I have a database with two tables this is the create statement for the tables:

```html
create table trein (
trein_id number primary key,
naam varchar2(100) not null unique,
zitplekken number);

create table wagon(
wagon_id number primary key,
naam varchar2(100) not null unique,
zitplekken number not null,
trein_naam_fk varchar2(100));
```

If I add a value to wagon.trein_naam_fk I want to get from the same row the value of zitplekken and add it to the related train.zitplekken. So i wrote this trigger for it:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KOPPELWAGON_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF TREIN_NAAM_FK on WAGON
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   V_ZITPLEKKEN_W number;
   V_ZITPLEKKEN_T number;
   V_TREIN_NAAM varchar(100);
BEGIN

   -- Haal zitplaatsen wagon op
   SELECT ZITPLEKKEN, TREIN_NAAM_FK INTO V_ZITPLEKKEN_W, V_TREIN_NAAM FROM WAGON WHERE NAAM = :OLD.NAAM;
   -- Verhoog zitplekken trein
   UPDATE TREIN SET ZITPLEKKEN = ZITPLEKKEN + V_ZITPLEKKEN_W WHERE NAAM = V_TREIN_NAAM;
END;

/
```

When i'm running the following update statement i'm getting a error:

```html
UPDATE WAGON SET TREIN_NAAM_FK = 't1' WHERE NAAM = 'w1';


Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE WAGON SET TREIN_NAAM_FK = 't1' WHERE NAAM = 'w1'
Error report -
ORA-04091: table RICHRAIL.WAGON is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "RICHRAIL.KOPPELWAGON_TRIGGER", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RICHRAIL.KOPPELWAGON_TRIGGER'
```

Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Comment: There are plenty of answered questions on this site explaining mutating table exception. There are several suggested in the **Related** section on the right side of this page. Have you looked at any of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select data from the same table within the trigger where the trigger is created, due to this conflict you are getting the issue. Even selecting of data from the same table is not requires as per my understanding, hence your trigger code should look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KOPPELWAGON_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF TREIN_NAAM_FK on WAGON
   FOR EACH ROW

/*DECLARE
   V_ZITPLEKKEN_W number;
   V_ZITPLEKKEN_T number;
   V_TREIN_NAAM varchar(100); */
BEGIN

   -- Haal zitplaatsen wagon op
--  SELECT ZITPLEKKEN, TREIN_NAAM_FK INTO V_ZITPLEKKEN_W, V_TREIN_NAAM FROM WAGON WHERE NAAM = :OLD.NAAM;
   -- Verhoog zitplekken trein
   UPDATE TREIN SET ZITPLEKKEN = ZITPLEKKEN + :OLD.ZITPLEKKEN WHERE NAAM = :OLD.TREIN_NAAM_FK;
END;
```

Comment: If you find the solution is appropriate you can mark this question answered!